# Extract data using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

How could I correlate the first (also second and third, etc) line of each function together? I meant I want to pick up the value of the first line of function 1, first line of function 2 and so on... Specially number of these lines  (between two #...#) are not always equal.

Let's say the values between (# -#) is one matrix.  I see that the problem is I need to break them down into different matrix and then equalize all these matrix to the same size by adding NaN values and then reconstruct them again. That is what I think but I dont know how to ask Matlab do these tasks.

Would you please give me a help?

Thank you very much !!

[image]

[image]

Comment: First step is to [read the data](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-import-and-export.html).

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel.
As I am very new to Matlab, I think I need to assign data as I load the data as well... And I still don't figure it out how I can like actually separate these different information into different matrix by this # symbol

Would you please kindly give me a clearer hint as I am quite new to matlab.
Thank you very much !